# How do I create a variable shared by a number of tasks in a role in Ansible?

Tags: variables, ansible

I am creating a task file in an Ansible role using the [best practice directory layout](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) e.g.

```
myscripts/roles
myscripts/roles/the_role
myscripts/roles/the_role/tasks
myscripts/roles/the_role/tasks/main.yml
```

In main.yml, I need to call a number of Java tasks so I have to specify the classpath each time e.g.

```
- name: java | Do something with Bar Java class
  action: command java -cp A.jar:B.jar:C.jar com.example.Bar myargs

- name: java | Do something with Foo Java class
  action: command java -cp A.jar:B.jar:C.jar com.example.Foo myOtherargs
```

so I would to use a variable to replace A.jar:B.jar:C.jar

I have been looking at the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html) and this [blog post](http://jpmens.net/2012/08/30/ansible-variables-variables-and-more-variables/). It seems possible to make a variable that is associated with a host or a group of hosts. However this variable should be associated with a task - how do I do that? You can [do it in a Playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/get_url.yml) but I can't get it to work because I have split the [Playbook into roles](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark,

You can create vars putting them in main.yml under vars.

Following your directory structure, it would be there :

```
myscripts/roles/the_role/vars/main.yml
```

See the [directory layout section](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) in the Best Practices page.

For instance :

```
class_path: "A.jar:B.jar:C.jar"
```

Then in your tasks :

```
- name: java | Do something with Bar Java class
  action: command java -cp {{ classpath }} com.example.Bar myargs

- name: java | Do something with Foo Java class
  action: command java -cp {{ classpath }} com.example.Foo myOtherargs
```

Good luck.